# Need to create Financial Year entries in Oracle 11g DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a financial year entries based on current or today's date AND time in Oracle11g DB.

Suppose if we consider today's date is 1ST April 2013, then i need the outputs as `01-APR-13` and `31-MAR-14`.

Our requirement financial Year considered is from April (the current year) to March (following year).

Based on current datetime...the scenario of output depends on the current date-time which  falls in the above said period or duration.

Another example: If we take today's datetime as 28th Dec 2012, then the output is needed as `01-APR-12` and `31-MAR-13`.

Please help how to acheive the same in very short format using only SQL.

Consider the below table as

```
Create table venky (financialYearFrom DATE NOTNULL, financialYearTo DATE NOTNULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something ugly:

```
   SELECT to_date('1-APR-'||(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+
                                (case when to_char(sysdate,'mm')>3 
                                 then 0 
                                 else -1 
                                 end))) AS start_date ,
      to_date('31-MAR-'||(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+
                                 (case when to_char(sysdate,'mm')>3 
                                  then 1 
                                  else 0 
                                  end))) end_date 
   FROM dual;
```

If `month > 3` then add a year to `31-MAR`(end_of_period), else substract a year to `1-APR` (start_of_period).

**UPDATE**: Something nicer:

```
select add_months(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-3),'yyyy'),3) as start_date ,
    add_months(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-3),'yyyy'),15)-1 as end_date 
   from dual
```

Substracting 3 months will send you to the correct start year. Truncating to year and adding 3 months sends you to 1 APR. End_of period is 12 months ahead start minus one day.

Comment: :that is so coool !!!!! Thanks a ton !!!! but can this be simplified ?? as i will be using this in a sub-query.

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: Guys ...if you feel the question is a genuine one then do upvote the question.. thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

create user define function for that here is example for SQL SERVER
find how to do it in oracle (both are same with minor diff in syntax)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getYear] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @CurDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Y int;
    SELECT @Y = CASE WHEN MONTH(@CurDate) <= 3 THEN YEAR(@CurDate) - 1 ELSE YEAR(@CurDate) END;

    RETURN '01-APR-' + LTRIM(STR(@Y)) + ' and 31-MAR-' + LTRIM(STR(@Y+1));
END
```

and use it like this

```
Select dbo.GETYEAR(GETDATE());
```

Comment: the ideea is nice, but: 1)the user wants pure sql(although a `deterministic` function I'm sure is ok). 2) If I write PL/SQL on sql server questions, almost sure I'll get "punches" :)